Layer "sequential" expects 1 input(s), but it received 48 input tensors
I'm trying to construct a simple neural network which gets a 2D Matrix (16x3) and outputs a single value, here is how I am trying to construct that network;
def GenerateModel():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.InputLayer((16,3)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(16*16, input_shape=(16,3)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(4*4))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))

    return model

Results of model.summary() is as follows;
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 dense_11 (Dense)            (None, 16, 256)           1024      
                                                                 
 dense_12 (Dense)            (None, 16, 16)            4112      
                                                                 
 flatten_1 (Flatten)         (None, 256)               0         
                                                                 
 dense_13 (Dense)            (None, 1)                 257       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 5,393
Trainable params: 5,393
Non-trainable params: 0

So when I try to create a model using GenerateModel and pass it the following matrix I get an error.
[[15, 81, -25.169450961198],
 [53, 108, -36.4360540112101],
 [73, 84, -40.6695085658194],
 [0, 69, -20.7084454809044],
 [35, 97, -31.3954623571617],
 [117, 102, -44.2065629437328],
 [48, 68, -35.7085340456925],
 [17, 59, -23.1078535464318],
 [64, 24, -24.2111029108488],
 [101, 2, -25.97821118996],
 [57, 35, -23.7173409519286],
 [117, 101, -44.1413580763786],
 [88, 10, -25.4001185503816],
 [11, 14, -22.0778253042297],
 [46, 50, -24.7021623105999],
 [0, 0, -1]]

The error is;
ValueError: Layer "sequential_5" expects 1 input(s), but it received 48 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=15>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=81>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=-25.169450961198>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=53>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=108>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=-36.4360540112101>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=73>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=84>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=-40.6695085658194>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=0>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=69>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=-20.7084454809044>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=35>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=97>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=-31.3954623571617>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=117>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=102>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=-44.2065629437328>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=48>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=68>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=-35.7085340456925>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=17>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=59>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=-23.1078535464318>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=64>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=24>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=-24.2111029108488>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=101>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=2>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=-25.97821118996>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=57>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=35>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=-23.7173409519286>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=117>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=101>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=-44.1413580763786>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=88>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=10>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=-25.4001185503816>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=11>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=14>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=-22.0778253042297>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=46>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=50>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=-24.7021623105999>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=0>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=0>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=-1>]

How can I fix this?
I also tried to generate my network as follows;
def GenerateModel():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(16*16, input_shape=(16,3)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(4*4))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))

    return model

and also this;
def GenerateModel():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.InputLayer((16,3)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(16*16))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(4*4))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))

    return model

I tried to add a Flatten layer after different layers, did not solve my problem.
How can this be solved?

Two mistakes in your code

You must flatten the input before the first dense layer. I'm not sure why you've placed it in between dense layers.
The model expects a batch of inputs. If it's just one example, you just pass it in a batch of size 1.

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def GenerateModel():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(16, 3)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))
    return model

input_matrix = np.array([[15, 81, -25.169450961198],
                         [53, 108, -36.4360540112101],
                         [73, 84, -40.6695085658194],
                         [0, 69, -20.7084454809044],
                         [35, 97, -31.3954623571617],
                         [117, 102, -44.2065629437328],
                         [48, 68, -35.7085340456925],
                         [17, 59, -23.1078535464318],
                         [64, 24, -24.2111029108488],
                         [101, 2, -25.97821118996],
                         [57, 35, -23.7173409519286],
                         [117, 101, -44.1413580763786],
                         [88, 10, -25.4001185503816],
                         [11, 14, -22.0778253042297],
                         [46, 50, -24.7021623105999],
                         [0, 0, -1]])

model = GenerateModel()

output = model.predict(np.expand_dims(input_matrix, axis=0))
print()
print(output)


